# State Machine, Model Validations and RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, state

Here's my current class definition and spec:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  # ...

  state_machine :initial => :not_started do

    event :game_started do
      transition :not_started => :in_progress
    end

    event :game_ended do
      transition :in_progress => :final
    end

    event :game_postponed do
      transition [:not_started, :in_progress] => :postponed
    end

    state :not_started, :in_progress, :postponed do
      validate :end_time_before_final
    end
  end

  def end_time_before_final
    return if end_time.blank?
    errors.add :end_time, "must be nil until event is final" if end_time.present?
  end

end

describe Event do
  context 'not started, in progress or postponed' do
    describe '.end_time_before_final' do
      ['not_started', 'in_progress', 'postponed'].each do |state|
        it 'should not allow end_time to be present' do
          event = Event.new(state: state, end_time: Time.now.utc)
          event.valid?
          event.errors[:end_time].size.should == 1
          event.errors[:end_time].should == ['must be nil until event is final']
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run the spec, I get two failures and one success.  I have no idea why.  For two of the states, the `return if end_time.blank?` statement in the `end_time_before_final` method evaluates to true when it should be false each time. 'postponed' is the only state that seems to pass. Any idea as to what might be happening here?

Comment: `before_transition :on => :game_ended` seems incomplete

Comment: Are the objects valid in your failing specs?

Comment: Removed the before_transition. Two of the objects are valid for :end_time and one is valid for :end_time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you're running into a caveat noted in the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/StateMachine/Integrations/ActiveModel):

> One *important* caveat here is that, due to a constraint in ActiveModel's validation
>      framework, custom validators will not work as expected when defined to run
>      in multiple states.  For example:
>
> ```
>  class Vehicle
>    include ActiveModel::Validations
>
>    state_machine do
>      ...
>      state :first_gear, :second_gear do
>        validate :speed_is_legal
>      end
>    end
>  end
> ```
>
> In this case, the :speed_is_legal validation will only get run
>      for the :second_gear state.  To avoid this, you can define your
>      custom validation like so:
>
> ```
>  class Vehicle
>    include ActiveModel::Validations
>
>    state_machine do
>      ...
>      state :first_gear, :second_gear do
>        validate {|vehicle| vehicle.speed_is_legal}
>      end
>    end
>  end
> ```

Comment: Sweet! Pays to read.  Thanks for being more observant than me.