# Rails cancan and State Machine - Authorizing states

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, cancan, state-machine

I've been using the two awesome gems, state_machine and cancan recently in my rails application but I'm curious as to the best way to integrate them cleanly.
Currently I've placed state transitions on buttons that go on actions authorized by the controller. This works perfectly, I can restrict who can perform that action.

I would like to give the user the ability to change the objects state in the edit form as well. I've noticed that state_machine will pick up on the state_event key in the hash, with the value of the action to perform (so it will go through all of state_machines callbacks).
This can be passed in with the params hash in update_attributes. Fantastic.

However only certain users should be able to change the object to certain states. How would I implement this?. The idea is that

```
params['state_event']=='move_to_x'
```

Should bail out for some users but be allowed for others. It also concerns me as until I implement this is the authorization part a clever user could post anything inside state event, even if they shouldn't be allowed too!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't actually as terrible as I thought, and I've done it in a way that keeps the code rather short and current_user out of my models (so big plus).

The trick was to call authorize again in the controller.

basically

```
def update
  authorize! params[:object][:state_event].to_sym, @object unless params[:object][:state_event].empty?
  .... etc
end
```

This way I can just aliases in Ability.rb. So users that can do the action will be authorized, and users that cannot will get the exception. This is also awesome as it's the same ability I'll be using on the button based actions.

The only caveat, is that you can't use @object.state_transistions to get a list of the available states the user can transition to, but it should be possible to do this via some sort of helper method.

UPDATE: though getting those states in a view like layer is easy enough

i'm using simple form so I just a collection input such that

```
 ..... collection: @object.status_transistions.select{|t| can? t.event, @object}
```

Which leaves the select with all the transistions the object can go through, and that the user is also authorized to do :).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two ways. Either by putting a condition on the transition. Something like this:

```
 transition :from => :parked, :to => :idling, :if => :valid_user
```

And create a valid_user method in your model.

```
def valid_user
  if User.current_user.has_role?(xyz)
    do baa
  end
end
```

(User.current_user.has_role?(xyz)) is not a valid test - you'll need your own.

Or you can use a custom state machine validation:

```
 state :first_gear, :second_gear do
   validate :speed_is_legal
```

There's a caveat found about this in the docs:

http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/StateMachine/Integrations/ActiveModel

There's another interesting post here:

[State Machine, Model Validations and RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643997/state-machine-model-validations-and-rspec)

We use both methods successfully in our application.

-- EDIT FOR THE MASSES --

Thinking about the comment about using current_user in a model. We thought about it a re-read our code. In the one or two examples we were using this, we realised we could remove the current_user method completely, thus eliminating any security risks.

Instead of calling User.current_user, we swapped to:

```
 self.users.first
```

This obviously assumes the model has_many users. You can then call this user's abilities

Comment: I get what your trying to do. But I was under the impression using Current_user like methods in the model level was bad.

Comment: It's not bad, in my opinion, it's just not common practice. We do it because we have to for stuff like state machine. Do a search for 'current user model' and you'll find a bunch of posts about why it's bad and why it's not.

Comment: I guess there's just a big part of me that dislikes using current user in the model layer. The biggest concern I have, is what if I have moved away from rails?. Or I'm trying to use the models in rails c. I need to then make the current user method available there, and need to make it accessible in the unit tests too. It seems awkward.

Still that being said, I'm happy with my solution which has prevented the authorization code from touching my models. It stays in the controller which is similar to the feel of how cancan is working.

Comment: I like your answer too and have refactored some of my methods. There is a problem with state machine though in that it is tricky to do some authorised things that don't involve a controller but do require a user. Am trying to figure out some other ways around this.

Comment: I'm super glad my questions/ponderings helped refactor some code out there :). Yeah I understand that point. I'm getting the biggest feeling that the best way is to keep state_machine and any sort of authorization completely apart. I'm not sure what tricky cases you've come up with though. If for some reason you absolutely required a user in state_machine, I'd say the best way to get the used is to pass it in from a controller. That way it could be any user, so your model isn't tied to the concept of current user.

Comment: Biggest issue now are some validations we run. Super admins can create x widgets and normals can create y. Just trying to get that out of a validate call. The world would be a worse place without SO :)