# How should admins interact with State Machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, state-machine

I've got a ruby app that uses a state machine pattern.  Users submit applications and, when approved and vetted, those applications will be visible to other users.

The app also uses ActiveAdmin to allow admins to move applications from a "draft" state to an an "approved" state and ultimately to either a "successfully published" state or a "retired" state.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to give the admin special rights to perform actions in all states.  For instance, I want the admin to be able to edit the application in any state, even though the user can't edit it once it's been approved.  I have an 'editable' method that is false be default, but I occasionally set to true when I want to allow the user to edit the application.

```
def editable?
  true
end
```

I thought of maybe creating a similar method called "admin_editable?" and setting it to true in all states.  But it seems like a hack.

Is there a best practice?  Should I just scrap the state machine all together?  Alternatively, how do I get allow the admins to edit a project regardless of its state?

Comment: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944703/rails-cancan-and-state-machine-authorizing-states

Answer (score 0):

Would a gem like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) help you here?

Comment: It's possible. I typically use CanCan to manage the behavior for users, but I suppose I could use it in this app to manage the behavior of applications.