# Multiple user levels for updating same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build one simple web site where users can write articles but admin needs to approve them before they show up on the web site. Also, after user creates article, article is not immediately sent to admin. User first needs to click on button "Send" on article properties.

I have this model:

```
create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "published",   default: false
    t.boolean  "sent",        default: false
end
```

After user creates article, `published` and `sent` are false. In article properties user has "Send" button. After he clicks that button, `published` is still false but `sent` is now true.  Now in admin control panel, admin sees new article and when he clicks button "Publish", both `published` and `sent` are now true. User who uploaded article can remove article and set `published` to false.

All actions I am doing for example like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Undo sent', article_path(article, :article => {:sent => false}), :method => :put %>
```

The problem is I don't know how to limit access. Regular user can change column `sent` to true and false but column `published` he can only change to false. Only admin can change column `published` to true and false.

How can I accomplish that inside my controller so it could be secure? All users have role column which I can access. Thank you.

Comment: Use CanCan for the permissions ;)

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I already have everything set up. I don't need CanCan :) This is probably only one small problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use something like a [state machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine):

```
#app/models/article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    state_machine :initial => :pending do

    #States
    state :draft
    state :pending do
        validates :title, :body,
            presence: { message: "Needs A Value!" }
    end 
    state :queued
    state :sent
    state :error

    #Publish
    event :publish do
        transition :draft => :pending, :if => :valid_user
    end

    #Queued
    event :queue do
        transition :pending => :queued, :if => :valid_user
    end

    #Sent
    event :sent do 
        transition :queued => :sent, :if => :valid_user
    end

    #Error
    event :error do
        transition all => :error, :if => :valid_user
    end
end
end
```

You can then use [this for the permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944703/rails-cancan-and-state-machine-authorizing-states) (used example code):

```
def valid_user
  if User.current_user.has_role?(xyz)
    do baa
  end
end
```